# How to get Value from HTML tag in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML tag like this available in jquery variable

```
var v = "<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=1>"
```

As per my requirement i need to get the Value from this HTML Tag i.e `1` and store it into another Jquery Variable.

Comment: **Answer:** `$('input[name="select"]').val()`

Comment: How about `v.val()` ?

Comment: **Answer 2:** `$(v).val()`

Comment: @Tushar, Right! But I was wondering if he has used the term `jquery variable`, It must be wrapped in `$` selector. I'm just making guessed :P

Comment: Give your id a value for example id="foo". Then try $("foo").val();

Comment: @Tushar Thank you so much ..Its working..

Comment: @Lara Welcome! Glad to help :)

Comment: @Lara Just curious, which answer helped you? first comment or second?

Comment: @Tushar I tried both and they r working but implemented the later one.If you answer , i will mark that as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something as simple as

```
var val = $(v).val();
```

```js
var v = "<input type='checkbox' name='select' id='' value=1>";
document.write($(v).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```